# How to make the sprite.BoundingRectangle fit the sprite exactly

Tags: libgdx

In LibGDX, I'm trying to create a game where you play a character who must survive waves of zombies. The plan is, when a zombie touches the player, the player loses health, and the zombie despawns; this works well until any of the sprites are rotated. Here's a screenshot of what I can imagine to be why:
[image: actual]

To check the collisions, I use:

```
if (sprite.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(Game.pl1.sprite.getBoundingRectangle())) {}
```

.. this is inside the `Zombie` class, and `Game.pl1.sprite` refers to the sprite belonging to the player.
So the red box is where I'm assuming the bounding rectangle is, based on where zombies despawn around it.
This is what I want the bounding rectangle to be:
[image: desired]

I'm not sure if I can achieve this just using `sprite.getBoundingRectangle` so I was thinking perhaps I would need to use Box2D or maybe convert the sprite to a texture.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the dimensions for a rectangle the size of the sprite if it wasn't rotated, and then rotate ***that***.